# Can IntroJS 'refresh' the highlighted elements after the intro is started?

Tags: javascript, web, intro.js

I have a problem when using introJS along with Backbone view:
My code for setting up introJS is like this:

```
introJs.setOptions({steps: [
  {element:"#id1", intro: "something about id1"},
  {element:"#id2", intro: "something about id2"},
]});
```

But in the first step, if the user do something in the highlighted area (#id1), the "#id2" element will be rerendered by the backbone view, causing introJS to fail when going to step 2.

Is there a way to 'refresh' the elements half way through the intro, so that in my case, #id2 can be found by introJS even if it is regenerated  after the intro starts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using inroJS only as an UI walkthrough then you can do the following

```
introjs.onbeforechange(function(targetElem){
    var jqElem = '#' + targetElem.id;
    $(jqElem).addClass('handle-events');
});
```

and

```
introjs.oncomplete(function() {
    $('.handle-events').removeClass('handle-events');
});
```

and in css you can add following lines

```
.handle-events {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```